# Easy way in Illustrator to create template of grommets for printing on banners?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5

Easy way in Illustrator to create template of grommets for printing on banners ?
I'm at a print shop and would like to know an easy way to create a quick and simple way to stroke an object with a grommet pattern.

Thanks

Comment: Please share an image of what you are trying to achieve (or something like it) so that we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a dashed stroke. Open your banner file.
Draw a rectangle 2 inches in from all sides (or however far from edge you put center of grommet). If your banner is 4' x 6' then make a rectangle 3'8"x 5'8" or appropriate inset for your application.

Give the rectangle a stroke and no fill. Make the stroke as wide as the inside of your grommet (you can enter inches or mm for stroke width, for instance type ".5 in" in the stroke window to make a half inch stroke.

Open the stroke window. Make corners and caps round. Check the "Dashed Line" box.

Enter 12 for the first dash. Now here's the cool part: for the first gap put how far apart you want the grommets to be (9 in, 18 in etc.)

Check the left dashed box selection, the one that makes it put dots in the corners. This should provide the following results:

[image]

[image]

Adjust the first dash to get dots round. You can save this stroke as its own file to be used with other banners.